# How to prevent F5 from being typed into html input on page reload

Tags: javascript, html, dom, keyup

I'm making a calculator app, I added an event listener to the document to listen to number keypresses, like so:

```
    function listenForKeyPress() {
       // add document event listener for all key presses
       document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
          // check to see if the keypress was a number
          if (/[0-9-+-\--.]/g.test(e.key)) {
             // check to see if the input is not already focused
             if (document.activeElement !== input) {
                // focus element
                input.focus();
                // focus value
                input.value += e.key;
             }
          }
      })
    }

    // call function
    listenForKeyPress();
```

The problem is when I refresh the page using F5 I get F5 typed into the input element, like so:
[image]

How can I prevent this from happening, thanks in advance.

Comment: You did not anchor your regex pattern at the start and end, so `F5` passed the check, because it has `5` in it.

Comment: (This would not even _need_ a regular expression, `e.key >= '0'  && e.key <= '9'` could perform the check whether the value only contains a single digit easily …)

Comment: @CBroe What about operators? `+-*/`

Comment: @JeremyThille oh, yeah, I overlooked that they apparently wanted to match those, too. Probably assumed that like with a regular calculator, pressing any of these operator buttons, would clear the display of the currently shown number. But if the full entered mathematical expression should get displayed, then of course my simple digit check alone does not do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can modify your regex like this :

1. Match only one character by starting with ^, ending with $ and removing the global /g flag
2. `[0-9-+-\--.]` is weird, as it matches `-` twice, and also the range "+" to "-" (char code 43 to 45). I think you want to prefer `[\d-+*\/.]` to match either a digit (`\d`), one of the operators `+-*/` or the dot.

Which gives :

```
const regex = /^[\d-+*\/.]$/;

regex.test("F5"); // false
regex.test("a"); // false
regex.test("5"); // true
regex.test("+"); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `isNaN(+variable)` as a check for a number in string. Regexp is way too expensive for a task this simple.

```js
['-5', '5', 'F5', ' 5'].forEach(value => {
  const valueAsNumber = +value;
  console.log(`"${value}" is ${isNaN(valueAsNumber) ? 'not' : ''} a number. (${valueAsNumber})`); 
})
```